# Wrap inner anchor tags of only the parent UL with jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, nested-lists

I'm having trouble finding the right selector for nested ULs. I have the following code:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="">top link 1</a></li>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">sub link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">sub link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">sub link 3/a></li>
  </ul></li>
  <li><a href="">top Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">top Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

This menu system is generated by our CMS so I'm trying to use jQuery to wrap only the inner "top link" anchors with `<strong><span>` to add more styling.

I've tried multiple versions of:

```
$('ul.menu:first li a').wrapInner('<strong><span>');
```

But I havent' had much luck. It seems to wrap all anchors inside of the UL. I'm sure there is some parent/child selector that I need to use but I'm not sure which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('ul.menu:first>li a').wrapInner('<strong><span>');`

Practice: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55Y8q/)

Comment: My actual UL was a bit more complicated than what I posted but I was able to achieve what I was looking for with:

    $('ul.menu:first>li>a').wrapInner('<strong><span>');

Thank you very much!